# compile error of "incompatible types when assigning to type char[2] from type int

Tags: c, sockets

I am having the above mentioned compile error. The line of code is this:

```
if ((strcmp(tempDept, data[1].Dept)==0) && tempCourse == data[i].course){
            if (tempDay = data[i].meet_days &&
                tempTime == data[i].start.hour){  //<---This line
                    printf("this worked");
            }
        }
```

Here is my structs declarations:

```
typedef enum {MW, TR} days;

typedef struct {
  int hour, min;
} Time;

typedef struct {
  char Dept[5];
  int course, sect;
  days meet_days;
  Time start, end;
  char instr[20];
} sched_record;
```

And here is my list off variables:

```
int switchInput;
int i = 0;
int tempCourse = 0;
char tempDept[5];
char tempDay[2];
int tempTime;
//char tempTime[1];
FILE *filePointer;
sched_record data[MAX_RECORD];
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tempDay = data[i].meet_days
```

This couses a problem because `tempDay` is char array of length 2 and `meet_days` is enum `days`. And in C constants in enums are just of `int` type. Another problem that you can't assign `int` to `char array` itself. Maybe you wanted an equal sign `==` ? 
Now you must think how to convert `int` enum value to `char[2]`. One way is use `sprintf()` to accomplish that. But concrete implementation depends on your interpretation of enum constants.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (tempDay = data[i].meet_days
```

You are missing the double equals sign ==

Comment: Well that solved the error but now I get a warning of `comparison between pointer and integer` on the line I added the double equal signs: `if (tempDay == data[i].meet_days &&`

Comment: @user1318371 you're trying to compare a string with an integer which won't work. You need to convert one to the other.

Comment: @SethCarnegie So I assum enum I declared above is a string? I did try this: `if ((strcmp(tempDay,data[i].meet_days)==0)` and got a `incompatible type for argument 2 of strcmp`

Comment: @user1318371 no, `tempDay` is an array of two `char`s.

Comment: @user1318371  enums are not strings but `int` so in this case `MW` is equivalent to `0`

Comment: @SethCarnegie What might be an answer?